# Unable to locate XML/Simple.pm in windows

Tags: windows, perl, strawberry-perl, xml-simple

I have strawberry perl installed in my C drive in windows and running
a build from an existing big project. During the build there are some
perl build scripts that needs to be executed and in the it throws the
below error message:

[image]

Below are the results of the commands I gave for verifying the existence of XML::Simple

[image]

I am wondering about the path `/usr/local/lib` in windows and perl is
installed in `C:\Strawberry\perl\bin` and XML::Simple is in
`C:\Strawberry\perl\vendor\lib\XML` and `C:\Strawberry\perl\lib\XML`.

**EDIT**: Output from `perl -V`. I have kept only for @INC

Built under MSWin32   Compiled at Aug  2 2020 19:51:20   @INC:

```
C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib
C:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib
C:/Strawberry/perl/lib
```

Comment: It's better to include output as text.

Comment: Before people bounce on the "close" button, this question is slightly different than the usual "just install the module".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the two situations are using different `perl` binaries with different library paths. When you run `perl` or `cpan`, you are using Strawberry Perl. Whatever you are doing at the top is likely using a different `perl`, perhaps from cygwin.

You need to install modules with the `perl` that wants to use them. Find the `cpan` for that `perl` (perhaps look in the *Makefile* to see how its finding `perl`, and `cpan` should be in the same directory).

Update your answer with the (text) output of `perl -V`. At the end of that output it will show the `@INC` directories. I'm guessing that list doesn't match the top image.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes I understand it is taking from another path and that's why I am wondering about this /usr/local/... and /user/lib/... paths in my Windows machine (PS: I have ubuntu app installed from the store). As requested I have updated with perl -V output for @INC.

Comment: I removed the cygwin from my environment path. Now it is taking properly and my build is running fine. Thanks for the quick support.

Comment: Normally, using the `cpan` from the correct `perl` is good enough. With the `cpan` that comes with SP, you have to make sure the correct `perl` comes first in the path (or use the more arcane `perl -MCPAN::Shell ...` approach)